# asp.net mvc & popup dialogs

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, modal-dialog

What do people recommend for creating popup's in ASP.Net MVC? I have used the AJAX toolkit and component art's methods in the web forms world and am looking something with similar capability.

What JQUERY plugins do people like? SimpleModal, JBOX (I think this was, what it was called)

Is it worth exploring pulling out the JavaScript from the AJAX toolkit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jqModal looks pretty cool http://dev.iceburg.net/jquery/jqModal/ - have only done some brief experiments, not used in production yet, but have put in the toybox for my current project.

Answer (score 1):

I like [lightBox](http://leandrovieira.com/projects/jquery/lightbox/)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using [Yahoo's YUI Dialog](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/container/dialog/index.html). Works pretty well, and you can easily hookup keyboard hooks like 'escape' to close. It dims the background of the page and is well tested across browsers.

Comment: Never looked at Yahoo's JS offerings but seems like a lot of people use them.